# Setup nginx configuration on WT-NMP

Tags: php, nginx

I have the following configuration added to nginx.conf:

```
server {
    server_name domain.vhost;
    root C:/WT-NMP/WWW/domain.vhost/web;

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }
    # DEV
    # This rule should only be placed on your development environment
    # In production, don't include this and don't deploy app_dev.php or config.php
    location ~ ^/(app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include nginx.fastcgi.conf;
        # When you are using symlinks to link the document root to the
        # current version of your application, you should pass the real
        # application path instead of the path to the symlink to PHP
        # FPM.
        # Otherwise, PHP's OPcache may not properly detect changes to
        # your PHP files (see https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/126
        # for more information).
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
    }
    # PROD
    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include nginx.fastcgi.conf;
        # When you are using symlinks to link the document root to the
        # current version of your application, you should pass the real
        # application path instead of the path to the symlink to PHP
        # FPM.
        # Otherwise, PHP's OPcache may not properly detect changes to
        # your PHP files (see https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/126
        # for more information).
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        # Prevents URIs that include the front controller. This will 404:
        # http://domain.tld/app.php/some-path
        # Remove the internal directive to allow URIs like this
        #internal;
    }

    error_log C:/WT-NMP/log/domain.vhost.error.log;
    access_log C:/WT-NMP/log/domain.vhost.access.log;
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't work. It does on my Ubuntu server. It does not on my windows WT-NMP nginx local machine. There are no logs showing up, and the only URL I can access is:

`domain.vhost/domain.vhost/web/app_dev.php/`, 
as when I enter `domain.vhost/` 
I get the list of files on server to choose from.

What's wrong?

Comment: Please specify in which way 'it does not work.'  Eg. process not running in background, web page gives error code 500, etc.  The fact that logs are not showing up is somewhat of a clue, if you are looking at the right place.  You may also be using / instead of \ for windows path delimiter.  Not sure if nginx config is smart enough to do the conversion by itself.

Answer (score 0):

You copy/pasted directives from your linux server without understanding them. The [WT-NMP](http://wtriple.com/wtnmp) server stack for Windows generates the Nginx config file when you create a new project. Start by creating a new project and carefully modifying it's configuration file `conf\domains.d\myProject.conf`, with directives from your other machine..

[WT-NMP: How to create a new Project](http://wtriple.com/wtnmp/howtos.php#How-to-create-a-new-Project)

And since you seem to use a custom sub directory for public files, read

[WT-NMP: How to change the root directory of a project](http://wtriple.com/wtnmp/howtos.php#How-to-change-the-root-directory-of-a-project)

Also, the [NGINX Documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/) should help..

Tips: do not copy `fastcgi_pass` or  `fastcgi_split_path_info` directives from your linux server